# email not being sent after appending a variable to msg["To"]

Tags: python

I am trying to append the variable `to` (which has an email id) to `msg["To"]` and send the email to this list. There is no error or anything, but the email isn't being sent. As soon as I remove the `to` variable from `msg["To"]`, the email is successfully sent. Where am I going wrong?

```
def email (body,subject,to):
    msg = MIMEText("%s" % body)
    msg["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
    msg["From"] = "service@company.com"
    msg["To"] = to + "username@company.com"
    msg["Subject"] = '%s' % subject
    p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t"], stdin=PIPE)
    p.communicate(msg.as_string())
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what's inside the `to` variable?

Comment: @Michael0x2a - its just another email id like username2@company.com

Comment: Consider using the `smtplib` python module. It's actually part of python, nothing to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to=to.strip() fixed it..

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that if you have an e-mail address, appending a second will just run them together.

```
to = "address1@example.com"
msg["To"] = to + "address2@example.com"
print msg["To"]
>>> address1@example.comaddress2@example.com
```

Needless to say, `address1@example.comaddress2@example.com` is not a valid e-mail address and any MTA is going to barf on it.

Per RFC 822 and its successors, MTAs expect commas between addresses, so:

```
msg["To"] = to + ", address2@example.com"
```

should work.